# Чем заменить Device.OpenUri? Visual studio ругается что метод устарел

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://google.com"));
```

Делаю приложение на Xamarin. Как сделать эту же операцию, но более новым способом?

Comment: Не уж то студия не говорит что использовать в замен? Вот например первая [ссылка](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8552) из гугла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел такой вариант. Все работает, а студия не ругается :)

```
Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("https://google.com"));
```

Читал что предыдущий вариант на новых Андройдах может не работать.